# How to show my full title when hiding adjacent cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My title is in A1, it is a large title. I am hiding column B. When I print preview, I lose half of my title because B is hidden. Is there any way to print the entire text in A1 correctly while hiding column B?

Comment: Make column A wide enough to display the title, or line wrap the title.

Comment: It would take the entire page for the A column, while A is used below as the start of my table, so I cannot make it wider. Line wrap would wrap A1 as big as 15 standard rows.

Comment: What happens if you merge `A1` with some other cells in the same row?

Comment: No change, the last part of the title remains half hidden. Thank you for the help...

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1407876/edit) to post a screencap of the spreadsheet and what it prints like? (you can upload images to imgur.com and link to them). At this point it would help to know what things look like, exactly

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just merging a few columns at the beginning and making them a little larger. I do not think there is a solution for this problem.